# What is this font in Cox, Little, O'Shea?

Tags: fonts

I am studying the book Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms by Cox, Little and O'Shea. I really like the font they are using, since it seems more "substantial" than just plain old Computer Modern. I understand how to make a custom proof environment, but I am unsure what the actual font is that they are using. It seems *very* similar to Computer Modern, but thicker, and I notice some fine differences here and there.
Here is the font I am looking for:

> [image]

Consider the following tiny differences. Here is a snippet directly from the book:

> [image]

And here is the corresponding snippet in Computer Modern (notice the difference in thickness):

> [image]

There are slight differences. For example in Computer Modern, the serifs on the "h" and "d" are straight, where as in their (the book's) font, they come down at a slight angle. Can anyone help me identify this font?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The font sure looks like a form of Times Roman to me...

Comment: @Mico  no no it is `newtxtext` 

Comment: newtxtext along with newtxmath did the trick.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's question was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts are newtxtext for text with newtxmath for math. See [newtx at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx). It's part of texlive.

Comment: From the comments.